# refresh label text with timer on database values

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is the code I wrote to get data from SQL server and show it by a label.
My goal is to get data when it is changed in the database, the value should be shown in the label by refreshing just the text. There is no specific number of labels to be added to the form, the number of labels is directly proportional to the row from the database.
I am dynamically creating labels and though labels appear they go behind the previous one.

> I want to clear the previous labels when new labels are appearing.

Am i doing it correct, where i went wrong ??

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionstring = "Data Source=DESKTOP;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    conn.Open();            

    //MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myconnectionstring);
    string getdept = "SELECT tran_desc,sum(tran_qty) as qty FROM bill_tran group by tran_desc";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getdept, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    for (int z = 0; z < dt.Rows.Count; z++)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
        string nm = dt.Rows[z][0].ToString();
        string qty = dt.Rows[z][1].ToString();            

        string getdept2 = "SELECT item,sum(qty) AS TotalQuantity FROM temp_dayin where item='" + nm + "' group by item";

        System.Windows.Forms.Label txt = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

        this.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = a * 28;
        txt.Left = 12;
        txt.Width = 600;
        txt.Height = 25;

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(getdept2, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        adapter2.Fill(dt2);
        string st = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < dt2.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            string nm2 = dt2.Rows[x][0].ToString();
            string qty2 = dt2.Rows[x][1].ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(nm + qty + nm2 + qty2);

            txt.Text = nm + qty2 + "-" + qty;
        }
        Controls.Add(txt);
        a += 1;
    }
}

private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: The for loop is putting the data in the last Textbox (txt.Text = nm + qty2 + "-" + qty;).  txt.Text is always the same box.  What I usually do is add the textboxes to a List.  So I create List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>();  then add to list  this.Controls.Add(txt); boxes.Add(txt).  Then I can later access the list as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be what you can do, have a panel, and add all your labels to the panel, and under `timer1_Tick` we can clear all the controls in panel and can re-add  new labels.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // clear all the controls under panel
    panel.Controls.Clear();

    // all your code to fetch the value from DB, and concatenate all
    // required columns to make your desired value.
    // set the label text as you value.
    // add labels to panel

    panel.Controls.Add(txt);
}

System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel = null;
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
    this.Controls.Add(panel);
}
```

Comment: when used panels it was not updated but i used **flowlayoutpanel** according to your guidance. Then worked 
Thank you man your guidelines are supered.
You have any idea how to change the text size of that dynamic panel??